# How to create web service using Database adapter in OSB Console?

Tags: database, soa, adapter, osb

I have a requirement to use OSB with DB Adapter as for given task, I believe BPEL Process will not be better performer than OSB. I have gone through some sites but all of them are demonstrating OEPE not OSB Console. Any response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I have similar requirement in my project and I was wondering here and there. Here is final solution of the problem. I documented for you guys.

**Steps in JDeveloper**
1.  Create DB Connection in JDeveloper.
2.  Create a Generic Project.
3.  Create Project as SOA project and use Empty Composite.

**Steps to create DB Adaptor**

1. Go to Composite Palette and choose AD Adaptor.
2. Drag and drop the DB Adaptor in the External Reference section (right side of Composite view).
3. It will open a wizard for selecting the connection and Other DB related process.
4. Give name to service that you want to create
5. Choose the DB Connection you have created already.
6. Move one with selecting your desired choice of Stored Procedure or Table (insert/Select) functionality that you want your web service to perform.
7. If you choose Table insert/Select then you can also choose the relation between tables as optional step.
8. Try to keep all steps default if you do not want any special features.
9. Once you finish all steps in wizard, then it will generate whole lot of files under your Project.
10. Look for 4 main files *.jca, xsd/*.xsd, *.mapping.xml, *.wsdl
11. If you see all these files generated well in your project then you are all set and we can move ahead. If not then look for the issue.

**Steps in WLS Console**
**Create Data Source**

1.Go to Left panel and choose Data Source.
2. Select New -- Generic Data Source
3. Give Name as you wish but for JNDI Name you have to use the connection name from the *.JCA file that you already have. Open the jca file and search for the ‘UIConnectionName’. This value will be used as JNDI name in data source creation.
4.  Choose Driver as oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
5.  Use the host and Port and other details that you had selected during DB Connection (in JDeveloper). This is obvious step.
6.  Choose target AdminServer.
7.  If you finish everything correctly. You are all set here and you can choose to test the connection and should be Test Success.

**Configure the DB Adaptor**

1. Go to Deployment on left hand panel.
2. In Deployed services. Search for DbAdaptor.
3. Click on the name DbAdaptor.
4. Select Configuration tab. And under it choose Outbound Connection Pool.
5. Here you will see (javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory)
6. Click on new.
7. Choose javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory
8. Next page will ask for JNDI Name. For this, you have to go to your *.jca file and choose the value which is already there for Connection-factory as Location (like connection-factory location=?). Use the value of Location as JNDI Name.
9. Transaction will be No Transaction. Choose this for now. This is need basis selection.
10. Leave other selection as is and then Finish.
11. Note : Once you finish. Go to Properties Tab again and look for a property name : xADataSourceName. Its value should be the same as UIConnectionName that you have in *.jca file. It should be populated. If not then you can set now as well. You have to double click on the value section and then write the name and press enter. Then Save it.
12. With above all steps we have set the DbAdaptor to point to same DB where we have our table/store procedure.

**What we did above is:**

•   We Have JCA File and WSDL for our service. Along with DB Setting.
•   We have a Data Source for our DB in WLS.
•   We have the deployed DbAdaptor in WLS which is pointing to the same JNDI.

Steps in OSB Console

1. Create a Project.
2. Create 3 folders under Project. Like Resources, Proxy Service, Business Service.
3. Activate your project.
4. In Resources folder. We have to add JCA Mapping. Point it to the *.jca we already have from above steps (We had created it JDeveloper). Just give the path and Save. It may give you Error. Ignore for Now.
5. In Resources Folder. Add a WSDL and give the path of your *.wsdl. If it give Error. Then ignore for now.
6. In Resources Folder. Add a XSD  and give path for the *.xsd we already have.
7. In Resources Folder. Add a XML and give path to the file *Mapping.xml.
8. Revisit resource WSDL again and click on its name. “Edit References”. Choose the XSD you already have and Save.
9. Revisit resource  JCA and click on its name and edit reference and point it to the mapping.xml
10. By now you will see all errors gone.
11. Activate your project.
12. Go to Left hand side and select the Business Service and Create Business Service by selecting the wsdl project.  On next page select Binding.
13. Then select JCA and give the ‘Location’ of IES (remember we have a value in connection-Factory in *.jca as Location. We had used it while creating DbAdaptor). Give that value here.
14. Move to next, next and next and finish.
15. Your business service is all set.
16. Now create a Proxy Service. Select Proxy Service and choose from B usiness Service option and do select the Business service you have create in above step.
17. Then click done
18. Activate your project.
19. That’s it we are all set. In proxy service you can click and see what is the End Point URl and keep it safe for your future reference. This is the url that we hav eto give on Client to call our service.
20. With this we all Done.

**Call from Client.**

1. Select SOAPUi for this purpose.
2. Create new project and give the end Point URL.
3. It will show all the services in it.
4. Select one service. Create Request.
5. Put the values in Request XML and Use the endpoint URL by appending your Localhost:port.
6. Click go and you will see the response back.

So, Finally : We are done with testing a OSB project with DB adaptor.

This looks long, but once you do it, its very easy for next services.

Thanks, Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

The OSB Console does not support **creation** of the JCA DB Adapters, and neither does OEPE.

You need to create the DB Adapter in JDeveloper and then import it via OEPE/OSB Console.  OEPE is easier ;-).

For a guide, see:
http://guidoschmutz.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/oracle-service-bus-11g-and-db-adapter-a-different-more-integrated-approach/

or

https://blogs.oracle.com/middleware/entry/using_jca_adapter_with_osb_11113